# PDO Insert from Web Form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, insert

What is wrong with the way that I am attempting a PDO insert using PHP and MySQL?

The MySQL database uses the same names as the ($_POST) variable.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {

//Declare Database Variables Here

$dblist = ($_POST);
$keys = array_keys($data);

$dbcols = join(', ', array_values($keys));
$data = join(', ',array_values($dblist));

$dbtype = "mysql";
$dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
$dbname = 'bpstalent';
$dbuser = 'root';
$psword = 'root';
$portno = 3306;

// if table_name is submitted, display dynamic table with another form request for table name

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';port=' . $portno . 'dbname=' . $dbname . ';' . $dbuser . ';' . $psword . ';' );

    echo "form submitted";

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'applicants'($dbcols) VALUES ($data)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

} 

else {

?>
```

html form here

```
<?
    ;}
?>
```

Comment: change `'applicants'` to `applicants`

Comment: echo out $sql `echo $sql` then use phpmyadmin or similar tool to see what the errors are.

Comment: send me the output of echo $sql;

Comment: it's strange that noone mentioned sql injection yet

Comment: Some mixture of strings and numbers in the values? not sure how a mysql insert statement will handle the absence of quote marks for strings.

Comment: *correcting per Radek's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, I think you're an easy target to SQL injection. I would change

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'applicants'($dbcols) VALUES ($data)";
```

and replace values of $dbcols with hard coded list of columns (they can come from an array as well, just not one sent by user)

For the $data I would replace that with params what are handled by bindValue(). You can accomplish that by replacing "," with ",:" to convert names to para place holders. If echoed Your final query would look something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO applicants (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (:col1, :col2, :col3)";
```

See this example in PHP docs, it will be worth your time to secure this form:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Below is a reworked sample of your script, untested, but should give you an idea of how to make things safer:

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {

    //HARDCODE COLUMNS, DO NOT RELY ON USER INPUT, BAD THINGS WILL HAPPEN IF YOU DO
    $keys = array("col1", "col2", "col3");

    $dbcols = '`'.join('`, `', $keys).'`';
    $placeholders = ':'.join(', :', $keys);

    //RUN THROUGH POST DATA LOOKING FOR YOUR KEYS, ONLY PASS TO DATABASE DATA YOU ARE EXPECTING TO SEE
    $data = array();
    foreach ($keys as $k)
    {
        $data[$k] =  $_POST[$k];
    }

    //CONSIDER REPLACING THIS WITH require_once() FILE
    $dbtype = "mysql";
    $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbname = 'bpstalent';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $psword = 'root';
    $portno = 3306;

    $pdo = new PDO("$dbtype:host=$dbhost;port=$portno;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $psword);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO applicants ($dbcols) VALUES ($placeholders)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
}
```

Comment: Cool, cool.  I'll give this a test.  I just realized that I need colons at the beginning of the col names.  Just to be clear, I should manually create an array using the names of each form field?  I've seen that in most examples, good to know that ppl practice this for a reason.

Comment: Yes, in your case you should hardcode those names so anything passed in SQL query is as controlled as possible. If using a framework like Symfony this is done via creation of Entity files (classes). The bottom line is to be paranoid about user input and vet as much as possible before executing a query. Also, if you're rolling this out by hand look into form validation, there is some stand-alone classes out there that will do some additional checking on form values for you, e.g. is it a number, is it 'x' characters long etc.

Comment: @Newbian you are supposed to follow at least *basic* syntax which you can learn from manual. And you mistaken this site with free coding service. The purpose of this site is not to bring you a working code on a plate. Your idea on PDO constructor parameters is quite wrong. If you can't create it dynamically from variables - better use hardcoded values instead.

Comment: I'll dive into the PDO documentation a bit more.  Thanks for all the help so far, not trying to mooch off of your superior experience ;)  Just got stuck and frustrated.

Comment: @Newbian if you don't get any error messages, then it should be your first and foremost concern. Setup PHP to report errors first.

Comment: It's Inserting into the MySQL table now.  Thank you all for your help!  This form obviously has a lot more work to go (validation, etc.) before it's any good, but at least I can see test data coming through now.